# Heatmap not working accordingly to my array value

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am currently trying to plot a concentration map in which it ranges from 0 (red) to 1 (blue). Here is the set of data (called `grid_list`) that I already have.

```py
[[0.96875    0.85964912 0.86585366 0.76388889]
 [0.77631579 0.72289157 0.65168539 0.63333333]
 [0.59047619 0.53535354 0.51886792 0.49074074]
 [0.47706422 0.512      0.51111111 0.43801653]]
```

The thing is that, everytime I try to plot it using a heatmap, it gives me something really weird. Here is an implementation that I have tried but failed:

```py
grid_list = np.array(grid_list)
im = self.axes1.imshow(grid_list, cmap='Wistia')
```

[image]

Im not so sure what I did wrong in this case.

Comment: Try `sns.heatmap(grid_list, cmap='GnBu')` where seaborn is a high-level API for matplotlib. [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6seT.png). Something else not shown is an issue with your code.

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

`imshow` works perfectly well with your data (as you have shown it to us).

Consequently, you've made a mistake in some other point of your code and until you show us all of your code (please don't) nobody can help you, and your question should be closed as your problem is not reproducible.

```
In [17]: import numpy as np
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: g = '0.97 0.86 0.87 0.76 0.78 0.72 0.65 0.63 0.59 0.53 0.52 0.49 0.48 0.51 0.51 0.44'
    ...: g = [float(x) for  x in g.split()]
    ...: g = np.array(g).reshape(4,4)
    ...: plt.imshow(g, norm=plt.Normalize(0,1), cmap='Wistia')
    ...: plt.colorbar()
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]